# Sort to get class definition before extending class

Tags: javascript, sorting

In JavaScript class definitions are not hoisted as functions are, which means that a class has be defined before it's used or in this case, extended.

I have a list of classes where some are extended and some are not.

```
class G
class F extends A
class B
class A extends D
class E
class C extends D
class D
```

I want to sort it to look something like this:

```
class B
class D
class E
class G
class A extends D
class F extends A
class C extends D
```

Let's say we have an array that looks like this:

```
myClasses = [{
  className: 'A',
  extendsClass: 'B'
}...and so on]
```

I start to just take out all non-extending classes and put it in the result first, but when I'm coming to the classes that is extending I don't know how to reason...

How can I sort the array to be in the correct order so that I can extend classes after they have been defined?

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for a topological sort.

Comment: What is your intended usage? When should it run? How are the classes organized? Or do you just want to sort your (rather limited) `myClasses` example array?

Comment: I generate the code for the classes from an Express class schema, and they are not necessarily ordered by the correct extending order in the schema. I started to have them in a single file each and then just import all in a index.ts. But now I want them to all be in the same file, which is where I am atm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help, it uses the array sorting function and a very ugly compare function:

```js
const parseClasses = classes =>
      classes
      .split ("\n")
      .map (x => x.replace ("class", ""))
      .map (x => x.split ("extends"))
      .map (xs => xs.map (x => x.replace (/ /g, "")))
      .map (xs => xs.length > 1
            ? ({className : xs[0], extendsClass: xs[1]})
            : ({className : xs[0]}))

const compare = (a, b) =>
      (a.extendsClass && b.extendsClass
       ? (a.className == b.extendsClass
          ? -1
          : (b.className == a.extendsClass
             ? 1
             : (a.extendsClass.localeCompare (b.extendsClass) == 0
                ? a.className.localeCompare (b.className)
                : a.extendsClass.localeCompare (b.extendsClass))))
       : (a.extendsClass
          ? 1
          : (b.extendsClass
             ? -1
             : a.className.localeCompare (b.className))))

console.log ("Classes A: ")
const classesA = `class G
class F extends A
class B
class A extends D
class E
class C extends D
class D`
const myClassesA = parseClasses (classesA)
myClassesA.sort (compare)
console.log (myClassesA)

console.log ()

console.log ("Classes B: ")
const classesB = `class G
class F extends A
class B
class A extends D
class E
class C extends F
class Y extends F
class Z extends F
class Q extends F
class M extends Q
class X extends M
class U extends Z
class D`
const myClassesB = parseClasses (classesB)
myClassesB.sort (compare)
console.log (myClassesB)
```

Comment: Nice. The compare function is exactly what I needed, although a bit hard to read nested ternary statements =P Thanks!